# TCP Optimizer for OS X?

Tags: macos, tcpip

Does anyone know of a utility similar to SpeedGuide.net's [TCP Optimizer](http://www.speedguide.net/downloads.php) or some other way to accomplish the same thing on Mac OS X (preferably with Snow Leopard)?

[image: Screenshot of TCP Optimizer Application running]

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Better download speeds, esp when web browsing.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check out any Linux based howto on this topic, Mac is also only a Unix system. Most guides you'll find online are targeted towards servers (although Mac based servers are really rare). The following was taken from [ESnet](http://fasterdata.es.net/host-tuning/osx/):

```
Apply these settings to /etc/sysctl.conf, and reboot:
# set this for hosts connected at 1GE or higher
net.inet.tcp.win_scale_factor=8
# for 10G hosts it would be nice to increase this too, but
# 4G seems to be the limit for some OSX installations
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=16777216
```

For a more in-depth discussion of the topic check the following lengthy post [Performance Tuning the Network Stack on Mac OS X](http://rolande.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/performance-tuning-the-network-stack-on-mac-osx-10-6/).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.